# templated class in Qt

Tags: qt, templates

Is it possible to use a templated class (not based on QObject and doesn't have Q_OBJECT macro) in Qt? I keep getting a linker error when trying to use a templated class. however, when I remove the template from the class, it compiles and links fine. I'm just trying to declare a local variable of type Filter, which uses a template, and I get this linker error:

```
error: undefined reference to `NumericFilter<int>::NumericFilter(int, int)'
```

***mainwindow.h***

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

***mainwindow.cpp***

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "filter.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    NumericFilter<int> filter(0, 1);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

***filter.h***

```
template <class T>
class NumericFilter {
  public:
    NumericFilter (int itemType, int val);

  protected:
    T m_val;
};
```

***filter.cpp***

```
#include "filter.h"
template <class T>
NumericFilter<T>::NumericFilter (int, int)
{

}
```

Note that if you remove the template in the declaration and source files and comment out the 'T' member, then it compiles fine.

Comment: Share the source code, please:)

Comment: Yes, this should work fine. You must be defining or instantiating the class incorrectly - share your code.

Comment: Just try to define `NumericFilter` in the header file only and get rid of filter.cpp.

Comment: OK, defining the functions in the header file worked, thanks. This is very disappointing though that I have to do this because the class definition is rather large.

Comment: Note that this is not in any way Qt-specific, but generic to C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/separate-template-fn-defn-from-decl.html

> If you compile and (try to) link these two .cpp files, most compilers will generate linker errors. There are two solutions for this. The first solution is to physically move the definition of the template function into the .h file, even if it is not an inline function.
>
> This solution may (or may not!) cause significant code bloat, meaning your executable size may increase dramatically (or, if your compiler is smart enough, may not; try it and see).
>   The other solution is to leave the definition of the template function in the .cpp file and simply add the line template void foo(); to that file:

```
// File "foo.cpp"
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.h"

template<typename T> void foo()
{
  std::cout << "Here I am!\n";
}

template void foo<int>();
```

So for your case, you would have in your .cpp file:

```
#include "filter.h"

template <class T>
NumericFilter<T>::NumericFilter(int, int)
{

}

template NumericFilter<int>::NumericFilter<int>(int, int); // added line!!!
```

Tada!  No compile errors!

BTW, parashift's explanations on templates in C++ are the best IMHO.

Hope that helps.